# UI design with buttons on click to invoke selenium testing java code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium testing. I have a requirement where I have to design UI with some buttons on click of button, I have to invoke Selenium java code method which will open an website and automatically pass some values to it. I have used Webdriver to invoke those methods onclick on the buttons from UI.

Problem is, I have hosted the code in server and I have given url to client. on click on the button from client browser, automation testing is happening in server side not in client side.

Please help me how can I test the website on clicking button in client side? Testing site have to open in client side not in server side.

Comment: If possible you can use Selenium grid. Setup a grid with client machine as a node. Your selenium code will run on sever/hub and browser will open in node.